# Connecting to Cloud SQL is failing

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, spring-cloud-gcp

I am trying to connect to GCP cloud sql using service account which has cloud editor role.I am following the example given here

[Spring cloud GCP postgres example using service account](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gcp/tree/master/spring-cloud-gcp-samples/spring-cloud-gcp-sql-postgres-sample)

my application.properties file

```
    # Set to the Postgres user you want to connect to; 'postgres' is the default user.
spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.cloud.gcp.sql.database-name=tablename
# This value is formatted in the form: [gcp-project-id]:[region]:[instance-name]
spring.cloud.gcp.sql.instance-connection-name=project-id:region:instancename
# So app starts despite "table already exists" errors.
spring.datasource.continue-on-error=true
# Enforces database initialization
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
spring.cloud.gcp.project-id=project-id
spring.cloud.gcp.credentials.location=file:src/main/resources/key.json
```

I am getting below credential error

```
 2020-05-11 17:10:21.494  INFO 99087 --- [nio-8085-exec-1] c.g.cloud.sql.core.CoreSocketFactory     : Connecting to Cloud SQL instance [[instance name] via SSL socket.
2020-05-11 17:10:21.494  INFO 99087 --- [nio-8085-exec-1] c.g.cloud.sql.core.CoreSocketFactory     : First Cloud SQL connection, generating RSA key pair.
2020-05-11 17:10:21.499 ERROR 99087 --- [nio-8085-exec-1] c.h.m.p.p.e.util.ExceptionManager        : Error occured

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.springframework.cloud.gcp.autoconfigure.sql.SqlCredentialFactory.create()Lcom/google/api/client/http/HttpRequestInitializer;
```

Answer (score 0):

based on this [link](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gcp/tree/master/spring-cloud-gcp-samples/spring-cloud-gcp-sql-postgres-sample) I think instead of:

```
spring.cloud.gcp.credentials.location=file:src/main/resources/key.json
```

You should use:

```
spring.cloud.gcp.sql.credentials.location=file:src/main/resources/key.json
```

Comment: @adorearun can you confirm this...  this is quite confusing as the `README.adoc` is saying to just uncomment, but it seems the property should be changed as well....

Comment: Yes uncomment and add the file location , changing like above answer also didnt do the trick.

Comment: Any luck with this issue? https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gcp/issues/1679

Comment: Another way to do that is passing base64 encoded sttring mentioned in https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-gcp/docs/1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/

`spring.cloud.gcp.credentials.encoded-key`